# Height of button grows 1px for smaller font size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap to create a button group.
When I changed font size of smaller class to 12px (14px by default), the height of the left button grows 1px. How can I avoid it? Checked by Chrome 26, Firefox 20.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button class="btn">
    Foo
    <div class="smaller" style="font-size: 12px;">
      Smaller
    </div>
  </button>
  <button class="btn">
    Bar
  </button>
</div>
```

Example is available at http://jsfiddle.net/kawachi/xkP9j/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set the `line-height` also

http://jsfiddle.net/xkP9j/5/

```
<div class="smaller" style="font-size: 12px;line-height: 12px;">
   Smaller
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the line height. You need to either remove the `line-height` attribute from `.btn` or you need to add it to `div.smaller` to match the `font-size`